# Definition of non-injective function

Tags: functions, logic, proof-verification

- Let $f\in F^{E}$ so to show that $f$ is non injective it's suffice to ﬁnd distinct elements in $E$ with equal images.
  $$f \text{ is non-injective } \iff \exists (x,y)\in E^{2} \text{ s.t } x\neq y \text{ with }  f(x)=f(y)  $$
- I wonder where did come that definition of non-injective

My proof:

note that
$$f \in F^{E} \text{ is an injection } \iff \biggl( \forall x,y \in E \text{ s.t } \underbrace{f(x)=f(y)}_{A} \implies \underbrace{x=y}_{B} \biggr) $$

Let $P$ the statement : $ \biggl( \forall x,y \in E \text{ s.t } f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y \biggr) $ then
$f$ is non-injective means that $\neg P$ is true for that we must prove that $P$ is false which means to suppose that $A$ is true and show that $B$ is flase  ( $\neg B$ is true )

- am i right

Comment: The negation of $P$ is indeed the statement "$\exists(x,y) \in E^2 \text{ s.t. } x \ne y \text{ with } f(x)=f(y)$" at the beginning of your question.

Comment: so if i noticed that no need to go further  and my proof is correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof is correct. It follows from the formal definition of injectivity ($P$) that if there exists even one counter-example, the function is no longer injective.

$\exists \; x, y \in E, \; x \neq y: f(x) = f(y)$

equals

$\neg \forall \; x, y \in E: f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y$

Which is the negation of $P$.

Comment: so it's call it Proof By Counterexample ?

Comment: @Educ No, what youve shown is that if there *exists* a counter-example, the statement no longer holds. To give a proof by counter-example means you point out one specific counter-example.

Comment: no i mean in case to show that $f$ is non-injective we use Proof By Counterexample

Comment: @Educ Say $f(t) = (t-1)(t-2)$. This function is not injective, as $f(1) = f(2) = 0$. So there exist values $u, v$ with $u \neq v$ so that $f(u) = f(v)$. This is how you would prove that $f$ is not injective using proof by counter-example. Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes of course that what i meant

Answer (score 1):

$P:(\forall x,y \in E: A\Rightarrow B)$ is false means is

$\exists x,y \in E: (A\Rightarrow B)^{'}$.

$\equiv \exists x,y \in E: (A^{'}\lor B)^{'}$

$\equiv \exists x,y \in E: (A^{''}\wedge B^{'})$

$\equiv \exists x,y \in E: (A \wedge B^{'})$

$\equiv \exists (x,y)\in E^{2} \mbox{ s.t } x\neq y \mbox{ with }  f(x)=f(y)$